# container div not expanding on the property min-height

Tags: html, height, css

I have the following CSS code for a div that I want to have a min-height and then the height increases as needed. I have no clue why but the CSS is not working in any browser! I tried to google the answer but yet wasn't able to!

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
.container {
  width: 1024px;  
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto; 
  right: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);   
  moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 1024px;
  min-height: 1024px;

  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #999;
  padding-bottom:60px;   
  position:relative;
}
```

The container div should grow on the increase of height of this div which increases as and when data is entered to the mysql table and then displayed inside this div:

```
.udis {
  float: left; 
  height: auto;
  width: 680px;
  position: relative; 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
  moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
  margin-left:10px;  
  min-height:620px;
  height:auto!important;
  height:620px;
}
```

Comment: What's currently happening instead?

Comment: Also, can you paste your html structure?

Comment: the height is stuck at 620px, the min-height thing is working good i guess and also i tried removing the height:620px; line but still no help

Answer (score 3):

Use overflow hidden in the container.
Or remove the float:left in the children.

You can read in google more about clearing floats
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

By the way, your three heights are correct, keep using them.

```
  height: auto !important;
  height: 1024px;
  min-height: 1024px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code

```
height: auto !important;
height: 1024px;
min-height: 1024px;
```

to

```
min-height: 1024px;
```

Comment: changed it in the container div, yet no response, the same height

Comment: do you have multiple divs with class " udis " ? If you want " udis " to expand according to data too, then remove all height attributes and retain only " min-height: 620px ".

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a fixed height for both elements, so the `min-height` settings never come into play. Change this in the `.container` style:

```
height: auto !important;
height: 1024px;
min-height: 1024px;
```

to:

```
min-height: 1024px;
```

and this in the `.udis` style:

```
min-height:620px;
height:auto!important;
height:620px;
```

to:

```
min-height:620px;
```